# Trying to find my GPS corners on property

Tags: gps

Based off the legal description Legal Description: TR IN 12-10-72 DESC: BEG AT NW COR, TH S 89 53' E 857.5 FT, S 0 3' W 1778 FT, N 89 53' W 857.5 FT, N 0 3' E 1778 FT TPOB CONT 35.0008 AC M/L..... I get that the property is basically 1778 feet by 857 feet, but it doesn't give me the four coordinates for the corners ...... How do I find these as I can enter them into my Garmin and come relatively close to the actual corners. I have no reason to know the exact corners as I wouldn't be building anywhere near the property lines I's more for when we are out there and just don't want to stray onto other peoples land.

Comment: Which coordinate reference system? For me is unclear what you asking

Comment: the legal description of my property only shows that BEG AT NW COR, TH S 89 53'  and then go a certain distance east then south then back west then back north. The problem being its not a flat field that i could just use a wheel to measure there is hills, cliffs and many other things in the way.

Comment: Depending on where you live, the county tax assessor's office may have maps of your land parcel.

Comment: If you are building, possibly close to the boundary, get a surveyor out to mark everything for you. DIYing this is a terrible idea, so please don't do it. You don't understand the documents, the legal location description, and your garmin GPS isn't going to be near enough accurate (10+ meters, even after corrections). Surveyors will understand all of it, and should be able to get much better accuracy, easily within a few inches.

BIG NOTE - If you are digging, call utilities as well and make sure there aren't gas lines and power lines below. Where I live we have "call before you dig".

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you live in the US from question.

What you have is a legal land description which is created by a surveyor or engineer.  They are created using the Public Land Survey System or Metes and Bounds and have nothing to do with GPS.  PLSS was created in the late 1700s, well before GPS, and Metes and Bounds was adopted from the British Empire.  They start from a known point, and measure out using angles and distance to plat out a parcel.

Additionally, you might only have a short or partial land description.  You can contact your county assessor to get the full description.  From this description you have given it could be a parcel 1778x857 section located anywhere, there is no context to location.  For parcels in the western part of the US where they use PLSS (what I am familar with) it will have Township, Range, Section and State the property is located; This will give your parcel some context.

With a full description it would be possible to get the GPS coordinates for your property.

**Warning: A full description, posted publicly, would allow any rando on the internet to find your house.**

Remember that many consumer grade GPS is only good down to 15 feet at best, and in my experience ~30 feet.

If you are totally uncertain to the boundaries of your property, or going to be building this close to your property line, it is well worth the few hundred dollars it would cost to get a surveyor out and actually mark your property lines.  It would save you a headache and a neighbour one too.

As someone in local government, a PSA:  Be sure to contact any building authority you might have to be sure you don't have any other restrictions placed upon where and how close to the property boundary you can build.

---

If you are just not wanting to stray on your neighbour's property, and having personally lived in a rural area.  Just look for common boundaries like fences, hedgerows, physical geography that might be where the boundary is located.  Don't do damaging activities near possible boundaries.  If you are asked to leave and you might be on their property, do leave.  Or meet your neighbour and talk to them about your shared boundary.  'Good fences make good neighbours'